# Is getting an invitation to the office during interview process a good sign?

Tags: interviewing, recruitment

I’ve already gone through 3 interviews for a position and the hiring manager is inviting me stop by the office. The order of my interviews were abnormal (hiring manager, recruiter, SVP) brining manager didn’t give much info as to why I’m invited into the office

Comment: I mean, it is certainly better than not hearing back from them...

Comment: I mean...what else were you hoping for?

Answer (score 10):

> Is getting an invitation to the office during interview process a good sign?

Yes, it is a good sign.

Some of the things they could do in this in-person interview or meeting are:

1. They want to get to know you in person and see your interactions
   with team members in the work environment.
2. They may even want to give you a brief tour of the facility.
3. They may also have an in-person interview.

---

BTW, you could also send the manager or the recruiter an email asking them about the purpose of this interview so that you can prepare well for it.

---

Generally, this in-person meeting is a good sign because if they didn't want to move you forward in the interview process, they could simply either ignore you or send you a generic rejection email.

---

Comment: If you get a tour, be happy, it's a positive sign.  Also, don't say anything about the facilities that could be interpreted as a complaint.

Answer (score 5):

Interviews are a two-way process - once past the initial weeding out of clearly unsuitable candidates, they are trying to sell themselves to you as much as you are to them. Showing off their working environment is part of that sales process. So yes, it is a good sign, they want you to see more of them.

It might also turn out to reveal a deal-breaker for you, in which case it's much better discovered at this stage rather than after you've accepted an offer. (Yes, this does sometimes happen - I did an on-site interview at one company where they had heavy rock music playing in the developers' rooms all day; they thought that was a selling point, I thought it was a major WTF)

Answer (score 2):

Your application must have made a good impression if you were invited to an interview. An interview is a conversation between an employer and you to see if you are a good fit for the position. If you want to succeed in the interview, you need to get ready for it.